# Contract deployment is raising gas issue while transaction and issue vary on various networks

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ico

I have just write a ERC20 based contract in solidity for my token crowdsale and tested it on different networks like rinkeby, ropsten and even testrpc.

When i compile my code on testrpc it works fine. When i compile and deploy my contract on rinkeby it gives me error of Gas limit exceeds while doing transaction and fails the transaction. When i compile and deploy ,y contract on ropsten it not give me any gas error but it demand very low gas to make transaction "31000 gas" and after that it also fails the transaction.

Kindly guide me where I'm wrong and what's the best solution for it.

Token Code :

```
 pragma solidity 0.4.17;

import "./MintableToken.sol";
import "./UpgradeableToken.sol";

/**
 *  Ethereum token.
 */
contract MyToken is MintableToken, UpgradeableToken {

  string public name = "Token";
  string public symbol = "TKN";
  uint256 public decimals = 8;
  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 300000000 * (10**8);

  // supply upgrade owner as the contract creation account
  function MyToken() UpgradeableToken(msg.sender) {
    totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  }
}
```

Crowdsale Contract :

```
pragma solidity 0.4.17;

import './MyToken.sol';
import './math/SafeMath.sol';
import './Haltable.sol';
import './ownership/Ownable.sol';

/**
 * @title Crowdsale
 *  crowdsale contract based on Open Zeppelin and TokenMarket
 * This crowdsale is modified to have a presale time period
 * A whitelist function is added to allow discounts. There are
 * three tiers of tokens purchased per wei based on msg value.
 * A finalization function can be called by the owner to issue 
 * token reserves, close minting, and transfer token ownership 
 * away from the crowdsale and back to the owner.
 */
contract Crowdsale is Ownable, Haltable {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  // The token being sold
  JobGoToken public token;

  // presale, start and end timestamps where investments are allowed
  uint256 public presaleStartTime;
  uint256 public startTime;
  uint256 public endTime;

  // How many distinct addresses have purchased
  uint public purchaserCount = 0;

  // address where funds are collected
  address public wallet;

  // how many token units a buyer gets per ether
  uint256 public baseRate = 2000;

  // how many token units a buyer gets per ether with tier 2 5% discount
  uint256 public tierTwoRate = 2100;

  // how many token units a buyer gets per ether with tier 3 10% discount
  uint256 public tierThreeRate = 2200;

  // how many token units a buyer gets per ether with a whitelisted 15% discount
  uint256 public whitelistRate = 2300;

  // the minimimum presale purchase amount in ether
  uint256 public tierOnePurchase = 75 * 10**8;

  // the second tier discount presale purchase amount in ether
  uint256 public tierTwoPurchase = 150 * 10**8;

  // the second tier discount presale purchase amount in ether
  uint256 public tierThreePurchase = 300 * 10**8;

  // amount of raised money in wei
  uint256 public weiRaised;

  // Total amount to be sold in ether
  uint256 public cap = 80000 * 10**18;

  // Total amount to be sold in the presale in. cap/2
  uint256 public presaleCap = 80000 * 10**18;

  // Is the contract finalized
  bool public isFinalized = false;

  // How much ETH each address has invested to this crowdsale
  mapping (address => uint256) public purchasedAmountOf;

  // How many tokens this crowdsale has credited for each investor address
  mapping (address => uint256) public tokenAmountOf;

  // Addresses of whitelisted presale investors.
  mapping (address => bool) public whitelist;

  /**
   * event for token purchase logging
   * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
   * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
   * @param value weis paid for purchase
   * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
   */ 
  event TokenPurchase(address indexed purchaser, address indexed beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);

  // Address early participation whitelist status changed
  event Whitelisted(address addr, bool status);

  // Crowdsale end time has been changed
  event EndsAtChanged(uint newEndsAt);

  event Finalized();

  function Crowdsale(uint256 _presaleStartTime, uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, address _wallet, address _token) {
    require(_startTime >= now);
    require(_presaleStartTime >= now && _presaleStartTime < _startTime);
    require(_endTime >= _startTime);
    require(_wallet != 0x0);
    require(_token != 0x0);

    token = MyToken(_token);
    wallet = _wallet;
    presaleStartTime = _presaleStartTime;
    startTime = _startTime;
    endTime = _endTime;
  }

  // fallback function can't accept ether
  function () {
   throw;
  }

  // default buy function
  function buy() public payable {
    buyTokens(msg.sender);
  }

  // low level token purchase function
  // owner may halt payments here
  function buyTokens(address beneficiary) stopInEmergency payable {
    require(beneficiary != 0x0);
    require(msg.value != 0);

    if(isPresale()) {
      require(validPrePurchase());
      buyPresale(beneficiary);
    } else {
      require(validPurchase());
      buySale(beneficiary);
    }
  }

  function buyPresale(address beneficiary) internal {
    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
    uint256 tokens = 0;

    // calculate discount
    if(whitelist[msg.sender]) {
      tokens = weiAmount.mul(whitelistRate);
    } else if(weiAmount < tierTwoPurchase) {
      // Not whitelisted so they must have sent over 75 ether 
      tokens = weiAmount.mul(baseRate);
    } else if(weiAmount < tierThreePurchase) {
      // Over 150 ether was sent
      tokens = weiAmount.mul(tierTwoRate);
    } else {
      // Over 300 ether was sent
      tokens = weiAmount.mul(tierThreeRate);
    }

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    // Update purchaser
    if(purchasedAmountOf[msg.sender] == 0) {
    purchaserCount++;
    }
    purchasedAmountOf[msg.sender] = purchasedAmountOf[msg.sender].add(msg.value);
    tokenAmountOf[msg.sender] = tokenAmountOf[msg.sender].add(tokens);

    token.mint(beneficiary, tokens);

    TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

    forwardFunds();
  }

  function buySale(address beneficiary) internal {
    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(baseRate);

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    // Update purchaser
    if(purchasedAmountOf[msg.sender] == 0) { 
      purchaserCount++;
    }
    purchasedAmountOf[msg.sender] = purchasedAmountOf[msg.sender].add(msg.value);
    tokenAmountOf[msg.sender] = tokenAmountOf[msg.sender].add(tokens);

    token.mint(beneficiary, tokens);

    TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

    forwardFunds();
  }

  /**
   * @dev Must be called after crowdsale ends, to do some extra finalization
   * work. Calls the contract's finalization function.
   */
  function finalize() onlyOwner {
    require(!isFinalized);
    require(hasEnded());

    finalization();
    Finalized();

    isFinalized = true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Finalization logic. We take the expected sale cap of 80000 
   * ether and find the difference from the actual minted tokens.
   * The remaining balance and 40% of total supply are minted 
   * to the Token team multisig wallet.
   */
  function finalization() internal {
    // calculate token amount to be created
    // expected tokens sold
    uint256 piTokens =  300000000 * (10**8);
    // get the difference of sold and expected
    uint256 tokens = piTokens.sub(token.totalSupply());
    // issue tokens to the multisig wallet
    token.mint(wallet, tokens);
    token.finishMinting();
    token.transferOwnership(msg.sender);
    token.releaseTokenTransfer();
  }

  // send ether to the fund collection wallet
  // override to create custom fund forwarding mechanisms
  function forwardFunds() internal {
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  // Allow the owner to update the presale whitelist
  function updateWhitelist(address _purchaser, bool _listed) onlyOwner {
    whitelist[_purchaser] = _listed;
    Whitelisted(_purchaser, _listed);
  }

  /**
   * Allow crowdsale owner to close early or extend the crowdsale.
   *
   * This is useful e.g. for a manual soft cap implementation:
   * - after X amount is reached determine manual closing
   *
   * This may put the crowdsale to an invalid state,
   * but we trust owners know what they are doing.
   *
   */
  function setEndsAt(uint time) onlyOwner {
    require(now < time);

    endTime = time;
    EndsAtChanged(endTime);
  }


  // @return true if the presale transaction can buy tokens
  function validPrePurchase() internal constant returns (bool) {
    // this asserts that the value is at least the lowest tier 
    // or the address has been whitelisted to purchase with less
    bool canPrePurchase = tierOnePurchase <= msg.value || whitelist[msg.sender];
    bool withinCap = weiRaised.add(msg.value) <= presaleCap;
    return canPrePurchase && withinCap;
  }

  // @return true if the transaction can buy tokens
  function validPurchase() internal constant returns (bool) {
    bool withinPeriod = now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
    bool withinCap = weiRaised.add(msg.value) <= cap;
    return withinPeriod && withinCap;
  }

  // @return true if crowdsale event has ended
  function hasEnded() public constant returns (bool) {
    bool capReached = weiRaised >= cap;
    return now > endTime || capReached;
  }

  // @return true if within presale time
  function isPresale() public constant returns (bool) {
    bool withinPresale = now >= presaleStartTime && now < startTime;
    return withinPresale;
  }

}
```

02_deploy_migrations:

```
var Token = artifacts.require('../contracts/MyToken.sol');
var Crowdsale = artifacts.require('../contracts/Crowdsale.sol');

module.exports = function(deployer) {

    Token.new().then(function(res) {
        deployer.deploy(Crowdsale, 1508861000, 1510402100, 1510402200, "0x9ff03cbbb57e6bc5ecfac92ce54b1fc58d6e7269", res.address);
        console.log("Token Address : " + res.address);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting time can't be in the past.

```
new Date(1508861000)
//Sun Jan 18 1970 12:07:41 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
new Date(1508861000000)
//Tue Oct 24 2017 18:03:20 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
```